# PIDinRootline for TCA mm relation for 'foreign_table_where'

Tags: typo3

I have an extension (Typo3 8.7.4) with categories in mm relation. The categories are saved in different pages. So i want to select only categories who are saved in the tree of a certain page and the subpages of this certain page. Is there a marker like the condition in typoscript "PIDinRootline" for selectin entries for foreign_table_where in TCA?

Comment: rootUid is the correct treeConfig parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rootUid ist the correct treeConfig

Comment: A good answer should explain the solution. Otherwise, a comment is perfectly fine. Also, if this is the solution to the question, you should check it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

The TCA `foreign_table_where` is documented on this page:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/ColumnsConfig/Type/Select.html#
An here you can find an explanation of the possible markers you can use in the query:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/ColumnsConfig/Type/Select.html#foreign-table-where

E.g. you can use `###CURRENT_PID###` to fetch records form the current page.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below typoscript.

This checks if one of the figures in "pages-uidl" is a PID (pages-uid) in the rootline:

```
[PIDinRootline = pages-uid, pages-uid, ...]
```

Do the same as PIDinRootline, except the current page-uid is excluded from check.

```
[PIDupinRootline = pages-uid, pages-uid, ...]
```