# Condition for treeLevel and IFSUB

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

Thx to Paweł Burzyński, only problem know is that hidden and deleted subpages should not be selected, regarding documentation this is the normal behaviour but they are selected. NumRows get true and css is added . i have tried selected.where = hidden=0 but nothing changed.

```
[treeLevel = 3]

  temp.headerdata = TEXT
  temp.headerdata {
    value = <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fileadmin/templates/css/msub.css">

    if.isTrue.numRows {
      pidInList = this
      table = pages
      #select.where = pid=this AND hidden=0 AND deleted=0
      select.where = hidden=0
    }
  }

  page.headerData.100 <temp.headerdata

  [global]
```

Is there a possibility to ask a condition like this
maybe with

```
[treeLevel = 3 && IFSUB]
  page.includeCSS.msub= fileadmin/templates/css/msub.css
[global]

[page|field = value]
```

I knew it would be better to use page backend layout field, but this is not possible in this project.

Comment: could you better explain what is the goal you like?

Comment: I want to add a css file depending on treeLevel and if the page have subpages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using numRows for table pages like this:

```
[treeLevel = 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    temp.headerdata = TEXT
    temp.headerdata {
        value = <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        if.isTrue.numRows {
            table = pages
        }
    }
    page.headerData.666 < temp.headerdata
[global]
```

Update, for hidden pages try this, it working on my TYPO3 7.6.X

```
[treeLevel = 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    temp.headerdata = TEXT
    temp.headerdata {
        value = <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style11213.css">
        if.isTrue.numRows {
            table = pages
            select.pidInList.field = page:uid
            select.where = (NOT hidden AND NOT deleted AND NOT nav_hide)
        }
    }
    page.headerData.666 < temp.headerdata
[global]
```

Answer (score 0):

> I knew it would be better to use page backend layout field, but this is not possible in this project.

If that field is used you still can use other fields (like `pages.layout`) or you add an own field to the pages record where editors can select the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can see here `PidinRootline`  [pidinrootline Condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45769162/pidinrootline-for-tca-mm-relation-for-foreign-table-where/45781400#45781400).

For TYPO3 Condition you can check [Here](http://www.pi-phi.de/19.html)